# Switching between my profile on Google+ and a page I manage

Tags: google-plus

I have a Google+ account. I manage a page there, too. But how to switch between them using an Android device that its version is 4.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

In the Google+ app, tap the "hamburger" menu in the upper left. It should show your cover image, your profile image and name, and a menu of options: Home, People, Photos, etc.

Tap the downpointing arrow next to your name.

You will probably<sup>1</sup> see an option to "Select Google+ page" with a right-pointing arrow. Tap that.

Now you should see your page(s) available in a menu. Tap it.

You are now using Google+ "as" that page.

To go back to your personal profile, follow the same steps, but choose your profile where before you chose your page.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you've done this before, then the page you used before will be listed here along with "Switch Google+ page" (if you have more than one page to manage). This also assumes that your Google+ account is set as a manager/owner of the page in question.